# Text style in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I overlay two contaners in flutter and write text on it and make the color of the text the same as the color of the first contaner.

```
Container(
decoration: BoxDecoration(
gradient: BackgroundGradients.standardGradient
),
child: Text("Star Session!", 
style:TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
fontSize: 30, 
color: Colors.transparent,
background: Paint()..color = Color.fromRGBO(248, 249, 250, 1.0),
),
textAlign: TextAlign.center, 
),
),
```

I tried to solve it by putting text directly on the container and saying white in the background and color: Colors.transparent, but it took the background of the text

Comment: When you need to overlay something did you consider using the stack widget? https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html